# Can't access resource bundle from custom framework using CoreFoundation

Tags: ios, frameworks, bundle, core-foundation

**What I've done**

I've built a custom iOS framework we'll call **CustomFramework.framework** as well as an accompanying resource bundle for some sqlite files called **CustomFramework.bundle**. I have added my framework and resource bundle to another project and it builds successfully.

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to access the resource bundle using **CoreFoundation**. I then want to select a specific sqlite file and open it.

**What is going wrong**

There is a file *within* my framework called **ResourceHelper.cpp**. Here is where I want to open the sqlite files. I am trying to get a reference to the bundle **CustomFramework.bundle**. To do so, I have this line:

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.mycompany.CustomFramework"));
```

and in my **CustomFramework-Info.plist** the `Bundle identifer` field is `com.mycompany.CustomFramework`. This line of code is returning **NULL**; in the debugger it looks like `mainBundle = (CFBundleRef) 0x0`.

**Why can't I locate my framework resource bundle?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working was I had to just append the bundle name to the main bundle path. Here is how it worked.

```
std::string dbName = "database";
std::string resourcePath = "CustomFramework.bundle/";

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFStringRef cf_dbName = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, dbName.c_str(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFStringRef cf_path = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, resourcePath.c_str(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

CFURLRef url = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, cf_dbName, CFSTR("sqlite"), cf_path);
```